# Is there a way to tell django-nose to handle multiple databases?

Tags: django, nose, django-nose

(Cross-posted here: https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose/issues/129)

In settings.py I have two databases listed:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql_pymysql',
        'NAME': 'OST_DEV_1',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'umc': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql_pymysql',
        'NAME': 'UMC',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

If I run the tests without REUSE_DB, they work, but slowly (nearly 2 minutes spent just on creating/destroying the databases):

```
bash
./manage.py test myapp
```

But this fails:

```
REUSE_DB=1 ./manage.py test myapp
DatabaseError: (1146, u"Table 'OST_DEV_1.tblMfg' doesn't exist")
```

This makes sense, as tblMfg is in the UMC database, not OST_DEV_1. Is there a way to tell django-nose where to find tblMfg? Note that my tests themselves don't reference tblMfg -- I'm sticking to 1+1 == 2 for now.

We currently use 'using' manually for tables that are in UMC:

```
active_mfgs = Mfg.objects.using('umc').filter(status="ACTIVE")
```